# Are there any good addon for remind you which axis is which?

Tags: 3d-view, add-on

After I click  <kbd>G</kbd>, I frequently need to think about whether the direction I want to move is x or y or z. I also disable the object move gizmo since I find it sometimes gets into my way of selecting adjacent stuff.

Are there any good addons to show you the current default X,Y,Z axis next to your selection, but are not move controllers that you can accidentally click on?

Answer (score 0):

You could just enable these Axis from the *Viewport Overlays*:
[image]

They should be on by default, strange why you don't see them. As you can see, these are not gizmos. If you even don't want these, just press the axis key on your keyboard, for example, `X`, `Y`, and `Z` for moving on each of their separate axes. You could also press `Shift` + the respective key of axes to move on 2 axes except for the one you pressed the key on.

You can change your axes to local from here or just double press the respective key on your keyboard for that:[image]

Comment: I want the axis location to change as I change my selection in the edit mode though. Also I want this to change as the transformation orientation changes. E.g. global, local, normal, etc.

Comment: @RuiLiu Check my edit, and also, it works in both edit and object mode, both.

Comment: Those axis are always global but I want to show local or other orientation as well. Also when you are working on a local part of the model, this is not always visible easily like the move gizmos.

Comment: @RuiLiu Check my edits. As for convenience well... What can I say ;)

Comment: That's not what I want. However, I have found out I can click middle mouse button while in g/r/s mode to quickly check which axis you want to constraint to. In case anyone need this.

Comment: @RuiLiu Yes, that option is available too, but you said "without clicking" so next time kindly frame your question more accurately :) At least you got it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the top, then click where it says *Global*, then select *Normal*.

Comment: Um... Isn't that already mentioned in the screenshot of the previous answer? Thanks ;)